# How to Get User Zip Code and Address?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am fairly new at using the Facebook C# SDK (server side for webforms, asp.net). How would you go about getting the user's address and zip code? It is a sub table, so I assume you first have to get the location id and then from that link to the location and then retrieve the address, zip, etc.

Anyone have any code they can share to point me in a direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook <strike>doesn't have this information (this may be not true for those using Facebook Credits and have provided this information aside Credit Card details) and</strike>  not providing any way to get it via API.

The only info you can get is Hometown and Current City (requires permissions from user).

**Update:**
Seems that Facebook do have this info and provide a way to get it by requesting `user_address` permission. Refer to post on Developers Blog for more details [User Address and Mobile Phone Number](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/446)

**Update2:**
Seems `address` field doesn't work anymore as noted in comment to post from link above

**Update3:**
[Improvements to Permissions for Address and Mobile Number](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447) post that came three days later have information about *"temporary"* disabling of this feature.

> We’ll be working to launch these updates as soon as possible, and will be temporarily disabling this feature until those changes are ready.

Comment: Hmmm, so their is no equivalent to this old method (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get most of the information:

A user's information can be retrieved by a call such as:
https://graph.facebook.com/me
(see [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/))

Once you have a user you can get the location id via:
response.location.id

If you use that id as [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) you will get an object that looks like this:

```
{
"name": "Hurricane, Utah",
"is_published": true,
"is_community_page": true,
"description": "blah...blah...blah",
"location": {
  "city": "Hurricane",
  "state": "UT",
  "country": "United States",
  "latitude": 37.1742,
  "longitude": -113.326
},
"checkins": 677,
"were_here_count": 14647,
"talking_about_count": 1391,
"category": "City",
"id": "112177375464163",
"link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Hurricane-Utah/112177375464163",
"likes": 1730
}
```

My Code (javascript):

```
var locationFunc = function (response) {
    document.getElementById('loginForm:fbCity').value = response.location.city;
    document.getElementById('loginForm:fbState').value = response.location.state;
hiddenBtn = document.getElementById('loginForm:hiddenBtn');
hiddenBtn.click();
}

var meFunc = function(response) {
document.getElementById('loginForm:fbUserID').value = response.id;
document.getElementById('loginForm:fbFirstName').value = response.first_name;
document.getElementById('loginForm:fbLastName').value = response.last_name;
document.getElementById('loginForm:fbEmail').value = response.email;
FB.api('/' + response.location.id, locationFunc);
}

var loginFunc = function (response) {
FB.api('/me', meFunc);
}

function fbAsyncInitLocal() {
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', (loginFunc));
}
window.fbAsyncInit = fbAsyncInitLocal;
```

My Code (JSF - ICEfaces):

```
<ice:inputText id="fbUserID" name="fbUserID" immediate="true" style="display:none"/>
<ice:inputText id="fbFirstName" name="fbFirstName" immediate="true" style="display:none"/>
<ice:inputText id="fbLastName" name="fbLastName" immediate="true" style="display:none"/>
<ice:inputText id="fbEmail" name="fbEmail" immediate="true" style="display:none"/>
<ice:inputText id="fbCity" name="fbCity" immediate="true" style="display:none"/>
<ice:inputText id="fbState" name="fbState" immediate="true" style="display:none"/>
<ice:commandButton id="hiddenBtn" name="hiddenBtn" action="#{CustomerBB.fbLoginAction}" immediate="true" style="display:none" />
```

Comment: Since my post 2 days ago the city state and country are no longer returning in the location object.  Very frustrating.  :(